# Trent Richardson timepicker doesn't work when site is deployed on IIS?

Tags: jquery, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, timepicker

I have used datetimepicker from [Trent Richardson](http://trentrichardson.com). This seems to be a quite popular time picker control across developer.
I am using Jquery 1.9.0, and jquery UI 1.10.0 libraries to support it.
I am developing a site using MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2012.
This works fine while running the site in Visual Studio. 
However,while deployed over IIS, the time picker does not appear at all, and I can see the its jquery file (jquery-timepicker.addon.js) loaded with an error saying "Function expected".

Did anyone else faced the same issue ever?
Any idea of how to sort it out?

Comment: When you script debug do you get any errors? If so what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sorted out the issue. It was MVC bundling creating the problem. This was working fine in development environment, but was not working well in IIS. 
I detached the relevant JQuery file from bundle and placed it as a direct source and it worked. Though it has sorted out the main issue, but I still don't understand what should be the reason for this particular JQuery file not working properly in IIS if bundled.